# Using two models in MVC application, one in a view and one in a partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having some trouble. I have a view as below

```
@model IEnumerable<Tipstr.Models.Posts>

<div class ="mainC">
<div class = "leftContent">


  @Html.Partial("_LeaderboardPartial")

</div>
<div class = "rightContent">
@foreach (var item in Model) {

        <h1 class ="ptitle">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)
            </h1>
   <p class ="date">
       posted @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date)
    </p>
<p class ="post">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.body)
  </p>
<hr />
}
</div>
</div>
    <div class="Cpad">
        <br class="clear" /><div class="Cbottom"></div><div class="Cbottomright">                           
    </div>
    </div>
```

And I have a partial, _LeaderboardPartial, as shown

```
 @model IEnumerable<Tipstr.Models.Leaderboard>


<table id="pattern-style-a" summary="Meeting Results">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Username</th>
        <th scope="col">Tipster Score</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {



    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userName)</td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.score)</td>

    </tr>

}
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

I can't seem to get it to work I think it has something to do with passing in one model from the layout and then another from the partial. How can I get around this? I get the following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Tipstr.Models.Posts]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Tipstr.Models.Leaderboard]'.

Comment: The model when the partial is rendered will still be the model used on the posts view. Are you trying to render a property of each post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Tansey said, you can have a view model that contains a reference to the two types

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(IEnumerable<Posts> posts, 
                       IEnumerable<Leaderboard> leaderboard)
    {
        //you can add null checks to ensure view model invariants

        this.Posts = posts;
        this.Leaderboard = leaderboard;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Posts> Posts { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Leaderboard> Leaderboard{ get; private set; }
}
```

And in your main view you will call Html.Partial like this

```
@model MyViewModel

<div class ="mainC">
<div class = "leftContent">


@Html.Partial("_LeaderboardPartial", this.Model.Leaderboard)

</div>
....
```

If you do this, you should change the foreach to iterate through Model.Posts instead of Model

```
@foreach (var item in this.Model.Posts)
```

Comment: I had already created the view model but I didn't know how to reference model.posts and model.leaderboard thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

`@Html.Partial("_LeaderboardPartial")` in the first view implies sending along its own model `IEnumerable<Tipstr.Models.Posts>` to the partial.

The partial expects a reference to type `IEnumerable<Tipstr.Models.Leaderboard>`.

Perhaps you need a view model that contains a reference to one of each of these types?

Comment: Okay I've tried
public class HomeViewModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<Tipstr.Models.Leaderboard> Leaderboard { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Tipstr.Models.Posts> Posts { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I got it working but thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the view model